# Invalid column ORA- 00904 error while inserting into table from view

Tags: oracle, plsql, view

In my main table having table structure column without double quotes but when in View column with double quotes. While inserting data from view into table then getting error.
Here is the table structure of **tbl**

```
create table tbl (ID number(10),
                  name varchar2(50),
                  addr varchar2(200));
```

While View is-

```
 create or replace view t_view as
 select "ID", "name", "addr"  from tbl;
```

While  inserting data into **tbl** from **t_view** -

```
insert into tbl
select * from t_view;
```

Then getting error `ORA- 00904: "addr": Invalid identifier`.

So how to resolve this issue, can i remove the double quotes from creation of view.

Comment: `"addr"` is a different column name than `addr`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-3C59E44A-5140-4BCA-B9E1-3039C8050C49

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all double quotes from everywhere in your code.

If you use them while creating objects, you'll have to use them **always**, specifying exactly same letter case.

Get rid of those, Oracle is - by default - case insensitive and treats all names as uppercase (but you can reference them any way you want, just don't use double quotes!).

Answer (score 0):

Oracle stores the name of any object in **UPPERCASE** by default. If you have provided double quotes then only Oracle stores the name of the object as it is.

- Double quotes - Case sensitive
- No quotes - Case insensitive - Stores the name in UPPERCASE

In your case, While writing the DDL of the table, you have not provided the name of the column in double quotes so your table name and column names are stored in UPPERCASE in the metadata.

You can see the same using the following query

```
select table_name, column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'TBL';
```

For giving your answer, create the view either of the following syntaxes:

```
create or replace view t_view as
 select ID, name, addr  from tbl; -- no double quotes

create or replace view t_view as
 select "ID", "NAME", "ADDR"  from tbl; -- UPPERCASE column names in double quotes
```

See the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4aac44a4c945782a165c8f0d35146957)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are trying to accomplish. Your request just doesn't make sense. Your intended statement

```
insert into tbl select * from t_view;
```

accomplishes exactly the same thing as

```
insert into tbl select * from tbl;
```

It's not that you cann't do this (you can), but it can only cause massive duplicate data issues or (hopefully) unique constraint violations.